# HighCharts with JSON Data from multiple php files

Tags: php, ajax, json, highcharts

I am new to HighCharts. I am making a pie chart with the data (JSON) coming form multiple php files. So i have used nested ajax calls. But I am stuck at how to integrate it into the chart data.

```
      $.getJSON("php/footprint1.php", function(data1) {
            $.getJSON("php/footprint2.php", function(data2) {
                $.getJSON("php/footprint3.php", function(data3) {
                    $.getJSON("php/footprint4.php", function(data4) {
                        $.getJSON("php/footprint5.php", function(data5) {
                            $.getJSON("php/footprint6.php", function(data6) {
                                chart.series[0].data[0][1] = data1.reponse.numFound;
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

The chart goes like this.

```
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'place2',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: { align: 'center', text: 'Foot-Prints Detected' },

       plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                center: ['50%', '50%']
            }
        },
       legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            width: 250,
             verticalAlign: 'middle',
            useHTML: true,


        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: [["BLOG",4],["PAID",4],["DIRECTORY",9],["WORDPRESS",7],["ADULT",7],["PHARMACEUTICALS",8]],
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '75%',
            showInLegend:true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Math.round(this.percentage*100)/100 + ' %';
                },
                distance: -25,
                color:'black'

            }
        }],
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of one of your PHP files? Is there a reason they have to be in that format? Generally, you are not going to want to make a ton of AJAX requests all in a row. That will introduce a lot of overhead and slow your page down.

Comment: Have you tried to update that points? Like this: `chart.series[0].data[0].update(data1.reponse.numFound)`.

Comment: Do you consider of using when() then() in jquery, instead of "json recurency" ?